# retained object not showing up in Xcode instruments using heap shot

Tags: ios, instruments

I may have an incomplete understanding of using allocations in instruments. I am trying to debug a retain cycle. At key points in my app I use 'Mark Generation' .
I am looking for a subclass of a UIViewController that never has it's dealloc method called when it goes out of scope. Checking the generation data under generations shows a lot of stuff but no Objects that were allocated during execution.. in fact there is nothing that I recognise from my code in here, no UI objects whatsoever. Perhaps I have missed a setting that records these things somewhere?

Comment: Did your memory actually grow between the shots? And if you hit simulate memory warning did the memory drops?

Comment: Yes it does seem to grow there is definitely something being allocated on the heap.

Comment: You could try hiding the system libraries, which may help you see your allocations. In the options on the right hand side select the middle tab (Display Settings), then under 'Call Tree' select the 'Hide System Libraries' option (if it's not already selected).